# How can i get current session used by @Transactional annotation in Hibernate/Spring Data?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactional

I have been executing stored procedure using Callable statement from datasource. Now this procedure has to read data from an insert query executed just before SP execution in same service. so this creates a problem as the whole service is wrapped around a @Transactional annotation and commit is only done after service completes. So , is there any way to get the current session of current @Transactional annotation . getCurrentSession of SessionFactory is giving me a differrent session.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your understanding is correct.
In @Transactional context, if you call getCurrentSession() method, it creates new Session object if it does not exist or returns Session which is attached to current transaction. OpenSession() method always creates new session. @Transactional helps you to extend scope of Session.

You can get current session inside the method (with @Transactional annotation ), by calling following method. And of course if you want to retrieve data , it depends in ISOLATION LEVEL.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

Session is open first time when getCurrentSession() is executed and it is closed when transaction ends and it is flushed before transaction commits.

in non-transactional context, if we call getCurrentSession() we get an exception .
And by default propagation is Required, make sure you dont have other propagation types.

And with following annotation in your configuration class, it enables it

@EnableTransactionManagement

Comment: Thanks Surya.  I am annotating my service method with @Transactional method. So i assume that a new session is opened as soon as we enter that method. But when i try to do a `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` , it is giving me an error saying that no transactional context is specified. i haven't specified anywhere if the 'hibernate.current_session_context_class' is 'thread' nor not. what do you think hibernate will take as its default session context? JTA?

Comment: How have you defined transaction manager bean in your application. If not create your transaction manager bean and see (debug) if that is loaded while your spring applications comes up . And is it annotation driven ?

Comment: I have created a new JpaTransactionManager using datasource picked up from JNDI.

Comment: Edited my answer to have transaction enabled in spring . If still not working, share your code in service class .

Answer (score 0):

If you using sessionfactory you can get by this code

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public Session getSession() {
    try {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
    }
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

Comment: For everyone stumbling upon this: Looks like the injection is not working anymore with the latest Spring version.